# Execute a grunt task from within a php script

Tags: php, gruntjs

I want to execute a grunt task in a php script with `exec('grunt')`, but I always get `127` back. Any other bash command is fine.

I even made a grunt.sh with

```
#!/bin/bash
grunt
```

and tried to execute via `exec('grunt.sh')`but that gets a `127` back either.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Have you tried to run exec() with an absolute path?

Comment: I did. But it it did not change.

Comment: Has grunt.sh execution permissions?

Comment: It has ;-) works fine if i execute it on command line myself.

Comment: What is the output for exec('echo $PATH') and `which grunt`?

Comment: 1.: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin 2.: grunt 0.4.5

Comment: I meant what is the output when you run `which grunt` on command line :)

Comment: I see, it's missing in $PATH. It is: /usr/local/bin/grunt but how do I add it? It seems to be some local $PATH only for Apache?

Comment: Are you running the PHP script through Apache/Nginx or from the CLI? They use different configuration.

Comment: I am running it on Apache2

Comment: Then maybe this helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable

Comment: You could try to run it using exec() but specifying the absolute paths for node and grunt. Run `which node` and try to run something like `exec('/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/local/grunt')`. A bit ugly but should work.

Comment: With '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/local/grunt' I now get an error 1. And it seems I did not get the envvar_ changed properly. I use MAMP. and changed it on several places but it seems it's getting it's vars from elsewhere

Comment: @Falc I want to thank you very VERY much for your help on this problem which took me about 5 hours this day you almost 1 :-). It finally worked with `exec('/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/grunt')` I just got `/usr/bin/local` instead of `/usr/local/bin`... Again: Thank you so much. Your help I very much appreciated.

Comment: @Jonathan if you found the solution you should label this question as answered and also you should express your solution in another post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the absolute paths to node and grunt. `exec('/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/grunt')`

(on OS X 10.10.4 – the paths differ on different OS of course)